# Docker Compose Spring Boot is not connecting to Elastic Search container

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, docker-compose

My Spring Boot backend application was working with Elastic Search container by connection to http://localhost:9200 before just fine. But when I dockerized my whole project my Spring Boot backend doesn't connect to Elastic Search container. I checked and elastic search container was working.

My docker-compose file below:

```
version: '1'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=hiretalent
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    volumes:
      - /hiretalent-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mynet

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.12
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    networks:
      - mynet

  backend:
    container_name: hiretalent-backend
    build:
      context: ./backend/hiretalent
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - db
      - selenium
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/hiretalent?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admin
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
      - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

EDITED: Here is the stack trace. It just doesn't connect...

```
backend        | Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:63) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.doExists(IndicesTemplate.java:177) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.exists(IndicesTemplate.java:169) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:83) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
backend        |        ... 128 common frames omitted
backend        | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        ... 138 common frames omitted
backend        | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
backend        |        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:930) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.7.1.jar!/:8.7.1]
backend        |        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.7.1.jar!/:8.7.1]
backend        |        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.7.1.jar!/:8.7.1]
backend        |        at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:153) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.7.1.jar!/:na]
backend        |        at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.exists(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:620) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.7.1.jar!/:na]
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(IndicesTemplate.java:177) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:71) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar!/:5.1.1]
backend        |        ... 137 common frames omitted
backend        | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
backend        |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[na:na]
backend        |        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar!/:4.4.16]
backend        |        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar!/:4.4.16]
backend        |        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar!/:4.4.16]
backend        |        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar!/:4.1.5]
backend        |        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar!/:4.1.5]
backend        |        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Do you have another MySQL running?

Comment: I have one mysql container but backend successfully connects to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing all of the internet I finally find the solution, turns out default value for "spring.elasticsearch.uris" is localhost:9200 and my container was trying to connect to nonexistent host all along.
I added "SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_URIS=elasticsearch:9200" to my backend environment in docker compose and now it's working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are trying to connect using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` , This mean when you are not using docker, and using localhost, You are accessing the host machine as usual.

When you are docorizing the application using docker compose and trying to access `localhost` as you used to do. You will access the container host which cant see the `elasticsearch`

To get over this issue, There are two ways.

First, is to update `localhost` with `host.docker.internal` this will work if you are mapping the ports. And this will case the backend to access the docker network.

Second suggested solution is to update to the name of the container, This way will access the container directly using `name:internal_port` combination

So you will have to repalce `localhost:9200` with `elasticsearch:9200` inside your code, and then it will be accessible as usual.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've done that but still I can't connect. ( I added this line to backend environment in docker compose "- SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER-NODES=elasticsearch:9200" )

Answer (score 0):

Try changing **localhost** with your PC IP ,which you can get with **ipconfig**  from command prompt

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've done that but still I can't connect. ( I added this line to backend environment in docker compose "- SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER-NODES=elasticsearch:9200" )

Comment: instead of elasticsearch:9200 try 192.144.5.200:9200(example try with your ip)